# Jquery find specific img attr (src)

Tags: jquery, image

Just knocking up an image switcher, and come across a small issue:

I've got three images hidden, and when hovering over the relevant thumbnail I want to add the class of current to the main image (to stop it being hidden).

```
$("#thumbs img").mouseenter(function(){

//this gets the url of the thumb
var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
//this removes the last 7 letters
imgSrc = imgSrc.slice(0,-7);
//this adds .jpg to the end
imgSrc = imgSrc + '.jpg';

//This removes all images class of current
$('#mainImg img').removeClass("current");

//I want this to find the image with the src of imgSrc and add the current class
$('#mainImg').find(img.attr("src",imgSrc)).addClass("current");
```

The last line is the issue, it doesn't work - any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate over the images and find the one with the correct source.  You can do this by changing your last line to the following:

```
$('#mainImg img').each(function(i,ele){
  if ($(this).attr("src") == imgSrc) { $(this).addClass("current"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#image'+$(this).attr('id')).addClass("current");
```

Try giving your images id 'image1', 'image2', etc and your thumbnails id '1', '2','3'. Then this should work. You'll have to iterate through all images to accomplish what you want with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to look for img which isn't a variable. What you should do is something like this:

```
$("#mainImg img").each()

...
loop through the images and check which one has the correct source then add the class to it
```

BUT i do think this is a bit over the top. Could you give us a sample code to work on? your process of getting the image by the source is not a good idea me thinks